# Correct permissions for node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm encountering issues with *node_modules* permissions and any package installed by `npm`. I am on OSX and the default is readable only by the user. I have to run a script before deploys in order to make this folder world readable (AWS Lambda specifically will not work otherwise).

I am not finding info on this. Are these the correct permissions? is there a way to change them?  I was using `nvm` and thought it may have been the issue but removing it doesn't seem to change this behavior.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, you should consider deploying without node_modules, and then have the server instance redownload the dependencies.

Comment: Standard permission error. I either had to change the perms or as you suggested not upload the node_modules.  My question is more informative - I don't have an issue with Lambdas - merely questioning if this is desired behavior by the npm developers or if I have a weird setup.

Comment: Actually on that note I just tried not uploading the node_modules and lambdas do not work. I don't think it will fetch it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, Im not too familiar with AWS Lambda

Comment: @cyberwombat What do you get if you type `umask` in a shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can own the default *node_modules* file.

That will only work for the current user. So if you are the only developer using that **mac**, try this solution in you Terminal:

```
chown $(id -un):$(id -Gn | cut -d' ' -f1) /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```